# Want to create an object in groovy to collect Jenkins pipeline stage data

Tags: groovy, notifications, jenkins-pipeline, report

I want to create a Jenkins pipeline report and want to send that report via Email.

Requirements:

- The report must have information about each separate stage.
- I want to create a class named Report, which contains a structure having methods to add and read report data from each stage.
- Create a single object for every stage that contains report data from each stage. Report data can be of MAP, String, or List.

EX:

```
pipeline(postBuild: {})
{ Stage("stage1"){echo hello}
  Stage("stage2"){echo from}
  Stage("stage3"){echo groovy}
  Stage("stage4"){echo and jenkins}
}
```

What I did is created a class name Report

```
@Singleton(lazy=true)
@ToString(includeNames=true, includeFields=true)
class Report {
    //  Will be collecting stage name and summary
    def stageName;
    def stageReport;
    def result;

    //method to set value
    def addStageReport(stageName, stageReport) {
        this.stageName = stageName;
        this.stageReport = stageReport;
        result.append(stageName);
        result.append(stageReport);
    }

    // method to get value
    def readStageReport() {
        return result;
    }
}
```

and I am creating an object of Report class to store each stage information

````
    pipeline(postBuild: {sendReport(report)}) //this will create report from data in report object and email to the user
    { 
      Stage('Check'){
      echo Checking
      Map stageName["Name":"check"]
      Map stageReport["Result":"success"]
      report.addStageReport(stageName, stageReport)
      }
      Stage('validate'){echo validating}
      Stage('build'){echo building}
      Stage("test"){echo testing}
    }
     ```
````

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Thanks, Patrice for your response. Update the question hope this will help

Comment: Thank you, that helps quite a bit already. But what is the result of this code, where does it not do what you want ?

Comment: I am getting few errors
```An error accured when reading advisory map definition: Cannot cast object '[]' with class 'java.util.LinkedList' to class 'java.util.Map' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.util.Map()```

and

 
```Cannot invoke method addStageReport() on null object
```

Comment: And also I removed singleton and tostring because due to that I was getting CPS function error.